# Do not understand source of "copy of slice" warning when doing a filter of columnsto assign a value to another column on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I understand this topic is an issue for many people who are pandas beginners but I still can't work it out from past questions.

I'm doing something very simple: Using boolean selection to filter rows in column X in a DF where the values are less than 1 so as to convert the values of column Y to nan.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/df1.csv", index_col="county")

filter = df1["columnX"] < 1

df1.columnY[filter] = np.nan
```

I got an :2: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. error.

I tried using loc thinking it might solve the problem but no difference.

```
df1.loc[:,"columnY"][filter] = np.nan
```

Have also looked around trying to make a copy of the DF but nothing seems to work.

Any help / explanation would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) accessor or [.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) accessor together with boolean select

Let get some data to work with

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,3,67,0,-12],'Y':[12,6,8,-1,-8]})
print(df)

    X   Y
0   1  12
1   3   6
2  67   8
3   0  -1
4 -12  -8

import numpy as np
m=df.X<1
df.loc[m,'Y']=np.nan
print(df)



   X     Y
0   1  12.0
1   3   6.0
2  67   8.0
3   0   NaN
4 -12   NaN
```

Comment: Oh Thanks great. How come that worked? I did not know you could put the boolean select in the loc like that.

Comment: Happy I was of help